# 1990s horror movie, possibly starts with the letter 'P'. Contains a winged demon that kills people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

The film is about a winged creature (a Demon?) that kills quite a lot of people in the film.

The film contains a woman with long red hair I think who at the end of the movie speaks 'Greek'(I think) to the creature. A chair is then used to kill the creature somehow.

One of the killing scenes with the creature involves a man fighting it in a room with a lamp.

The film possibly contains a professor I think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you actually watch this in the '90s or more recently than that? I ask because, on occasion, story-ID querents have stated that a movie was from the '70s/'80s/'90s, and it later transpired that said movie was much newer than that. Not saying that's the case here, but some clarification as to when you watched this would be appreciated.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prophecy?

Comment: Q - The Winged Serpent ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(1982_film)

Comment: My first thought for a film involving a flying monster and a title that starts with P is Pumpkinhead, but the other details don't seem to match.

Comment: You mention that it has wings - does it fly in the film? Is it human sized? Larger? Smaller?